# How to replace every instance of a string in a tkinter widget with another string

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to replace every instance of a string given by a simpledialog widget in a text box widget with another string given by another simpledialog using replace().

```
text_area = Text(window, font=(font_name.get(), font_size.get()))
to_replace = simpledialog.askstring(title="Replace", prompt="Enter text to be replaced") 
with_what_to_replace = simpledialog.askstring(title="Replace", prompt="Enter what to replace with")
text_area.replace(to_replace, with_what_to_replace)
```

I have tried to get around using replace() by manually inserting and deleting it but I can't keep the text in it's entirety.

The error that I receive by using replace()

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/python/Documents/OPEN Text editor/texteditor.py", line 99, in replace
    text_area.replace(to_replace, with_what_to_replace)
TypeError: Text.replace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'chars'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the definition of `Text.replace` function is:

```py
def replace(self, index1, index2, chars, *args)
```

What you use is for *string replace*, so you need to get the text from the text box, do the replace and then update the text of the text box as below:

```py
# get content of text box
text = text_area.get("1.0", "end-1c")
# clear text box
text_area.delete("1.0", "end")
# insert the replace result back to text box
text_area.insert("end", text.replace(to_replace, with_what_to_replace))
```

---

Updated: As pointed out by @Bryan, you can perform the replacement in-place in order to keep the structure of the content of the text box:

```py
# search all the occurrences of to_replace in the text box
result = text_area.tk.call(text_area._w, "search", "-all", to_replace, "1.0")
# size of the to_replace string
length = len(to_replace)
# do the replace in reverse order
for idx in result[::-1]:
    # find the end index of replacement
    end_idx = text_area.index(f"{idx}+{length}c")
    # perform the in-place replacement
    text_area.replace(idx, end_idx, with_what_to_replace)
```

Comment: If you have embedded widgets or images, or any sort of formatting in the text widget, that will all get destroyed. This will work OK if you only have text in the widget (which is pretty common, of course).

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, you're right.  Answer updated.